# stop FreeBSD virtual machine from booting as 'Live' in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, freebsd

i have had this problem before with other OS's. I could usually solve it by just rebooting from in the virt machine. 
But everytime i reboot or start a FreeBSD 32bit desktop it wants to reinstall itself.
The first thing that seems to kickoff is: /boots/loader/default.conf
Should i change something in this?
edit: after /BOOT/LOADER that is

Comment: freeBSD doesnt have tab-autocomplete? crap, is there some way to enable this?

Comment: Have you left the "disk" (usually an ISO) in the virtual CD drive?  If the VM is set to boot from the CD first, this could be your problem (although I don't know enough about FreeBSD to be sure).

Comment: @mbraedley: yeah, stupid of me, the boot order was set to cdrom first and i still had the iso in storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way it could try to reinstall itself is if:

1. It is still booting off the CDROM image
2. There is no `/sbin/init` but there is a `/sbin/systeminstall`

It is most likely option 1.  Try removing the ISO image from the CDROM drive configuration.

And as for tab completion, that's down to the shell.

You can either use `tcsh` as your shell (`chsh -s tcsh`) or install bash and use that:

As root:

```
# pkg_add -r bash
```

As your user:

```
$ chsh -s bash
```

Comment: @:matt: yeah #1 was my problem, thanks for the shell info also